# Calling a stored procedure with a cursor and a prepared statement results in a error 1064 near 'NULL'

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to write a stored procedure that will find all foreign key constraints in all tables contained within a database.  Currently, I have the following:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `dropForeignKeys`;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `dropForeignKeys`()
LANGUAGE SQL
DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
BEGIN
   DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
   DECLARE stmt CHAR(200);
   DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR FOR SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', TABLE_NAME, ' DROP FOREIGN KEY ', CONSTRAINT_NAME, ';')
   FROM information_schema.key_column_usage
   WHERE CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = DATABASE()
   AND referenced_table_name IS NOT NULL;
   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

   OPEN cursor1;

   execute_loop: LOOP
      FETCH cursor1 INTO @stmt;
      IF done THEN
         LEAVE execute_loop;
      END IF;
      PREPARE dropKeyStatement FROM @stmt;
      EXECUTE dropKeyStatement;
      DEALLOCATE PREPARE dropKeyStatement;
   END LOOP;

   CLOSE cursor1;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

The procedure itself will be created without any issues, but calling the stored procedure with `` CALL `dropForeignKeys`(); `` or `CALL dropForeignKeys();` results in the following error:

```
SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1
```

EDIT: I have fixed the problem, please see below for the working procedure statement.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `dropForeignKeys`;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `dropForeignKeys`()
LANGUAGE SQL
DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
BEGIN
   DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
   DECLARE stmt CHAR(200);
   DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR FOR SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', TABLE_NAME, ' DROP FOREIGN KEY ', CONSTRAINT_NAME, ';')
   FROM information_schema.key_column_usage
   WHERE CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = DATABASE()
   AND referenced_table_name IS NOT NULL;
   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

   OPEN cursor1;

   execute_loop: LOOP
      FETCH cursor1 INTO stmt;
      IF done THEN
         LEAVE execute_loop;
      END IF;
      SET @stmtBody = stmt;
      PREPARE dropKeyStatement FROM @stmtBody;
      EXECUTE dropKeyStatement;
      DEALLOCATE PREPARE dropKeyStatement;
   END LOOP;

   CLOSE cursor1;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Try leaving out the line `AND referenced_table_name IS NOT NULL` ?

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't help.

Comment: Try `SHOW ERRORS` ?

Comment: I'd check what the variable `@stmt` contains after you run the procedure. Since it's a user-defined variable, it will retain its value after the procedure exits, as long as you query it in the same session. It's important to see the full query. It seems like you have a table or a constraint literally named "NULL" which is a [reserved keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html). So you should put it in back-ticks in your dynamic SQL statement.

Comment: I restored the ```AND referenced_table_name IS NOT NULL```, commented out the PREPARE, EXECUTE, and DEALLOCATE statements and replaced them with a single ```SELECT stmt``` and I can confirm that none of the statements generated contain any instance of the word NULL.

Comment: ```SHOW ERRORS``` simply produces the error I provided up above.

Comment: Are you sure the error occurs only from this procedure? Perhaps it is caused by a different procedure or a different SQL statement than the one you show above.

Comment: 100% certain.  However, I have found the source of the problem and will update the question with the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the issue, please see below for the corrected code:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `dropForeignKeys`;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `dropForeignKeys`()
LANGUAGE SQL
DETERMINISTIC
CONTAINS SQL
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
BEGIN
   DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
   DECLARE stmt CHAR(200);
   DECLARE cursor1 CURSOR FOR SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ', TABLE_NAME, ' DROP FOREIGN KEY ', CONSTRAINT_NAME, ';')
   FROM information_schema.key_column_usage
   WHERE CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = DATABASE()
   AND referenced_table_name IS NOT NULL;
   DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

   OPEN cursor1;

   execute_loop: LOOP
      FETCH cursor1 INTO stmt;
      IF done THEN
         LEAVE execute_loop;
      END IF;
      SET @stmtBody = stmt;
      PREPARE dropKeyStatement FROM @stmtBody;
      EXECUTE dropKeyStatement;
      DEALLOCATE PREPARE dropKeyStatement;
   END LOOP;

   CLOSE cursor1;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Could you provide more detail in your SQL design?